# Android Custom System Keyboard With API Call and Marshmallow Permissions

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am planning to make a custom android system keyboard that can be used by users with the *following abilities*:

1. Clicking some key will hide current keyboard and show custom view that accesses phone contacts list with android **Marshmallow** permissions to be considered.
2. Do an **API call** inside current custom view.
3. Implement some banking services (**payment gateways**) in a separate view.

***My Questions:***

1. Can I implement **all** previous features using current Android framework?
2. If yes, Is it **allowed** to submit this app to the **Play Store** without any reject reasons by Google?

By the way, this is not an exercise. I read a lot of articles and did not find a clue to help my research.

Would appreciate some expert answers!